# Is there a way to run full screen legacy programs in Windows 8 Modern mode?

Tags: windows-8, android, modern-ui, multiple-desktop

I know most people are looking for the other way around and that is doable with Stardock's ModernMix, but I want to do the reverse. Lets say I'm running a full screen game or other program that is full screen. Instead of using alt tab, I'd like to swipe from the left to change to another legacy program or switch to the desktop.

It doesn't have to be something in Windows 8, but something similar with third party programs is also fine. Thanks.

P.S. Just to be very specific, Im using Windroy to emulate android on my surface pro 2. it has the option to use full screen, which is what I would like to have. Unfortunately, when in full screen, I cant get out of it and go back to desktop. I can however swipe from the left and access other modern ui apps. This 
is why Im asking 
this question.

Comment: What you want is not possible.  If you are unable to  exit "Full Scren" mode with Windroy report it as a bug because thats a bug.

Comment: Okay thanks, I kinda suspected this might not be possible. I did find out how to get out the program though and it is by tapping the top edge of the screen which is not mentioned anywhere, probably because they assume Id have a mouse and keyboard which I dont on my surface pro. Not very convenient. You'd think that they would optimize it for touchscreens since android is a to touch OS.